# How do we dump data into informatica?

Tags: informatica

I have to dump data from various sources to Informatica. Sources are some manual files which would be dumped via a SFTP server, some via APIs, some with direct DB connection. In that case, how do we connect the files from the server? via some kind of connection to the SFTP server, API endpoint connection, putting DB connection via DB endpoint? In these cases, how do we authenticate? i dont want to use the username/password, is there a way to use Active Directory connect?

Comment: What do you mean by "dump data to Informatica"? Informatica is an ETL tool, it has no storage, so you can't "dump" data into it

Comment: to add to it, you can connect to n number of sources - be if db, file, cloud. db and clouds are mostly connected via odbc/jdbc. files - FTP/SFTP

Comment: Understood.. So through informatica, if we are storing the data to a data warehouse.. How does informatica authenticate if the source of the files are genuine.. Also any way to scan for malicious files??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How does informatica authenticate if the source of the files are genuine?

- If you mean the source itself, then you need to decide if the source is genuine before you create a connection to it
- If you mean how to secure the connection, then that is a property of the source and defined by the owner of the source. Informatica can use almost any industry-standard secure protocols and authentication methods

Any way to scan for malicious files?

1. Informatica can implement any business rules you want to define to determine if the data in a file is malicious
2. If you are asking is there a "magic button" you can press that will tell you if a file is malicious, then the answer is no

**Answer to Question about PocketETL**

Once you've identified all the functionality required to implement your overall architecture, you have 2 basic options for how you satisfy these requirements:

1. Identify a single tool that covers as much of the functionality as possible and then fill in the gaps with other tools

- simplest to implement
- should "just work"
- unlikely to be "best of breed" in all areas
- unlikely to the cheapest solution

2. Implement point solutions for each area of functionality

- likely to be a better solution, for you, in each area
- may be cheaper
- but you have to get all the components working together, which is unlikely to be trivial
- you need to know how to implement and configure multiple products, not just one

So you could use Informatica to do everything or you could use PocketETL to do the first piece of data movement and then other tools to implement the rest of data pipeline

Comment: have you heard of Pocket ETL tool ? This perhaps is used to place data file(s) to warehouse via Informatica

Comment: PocketETL is an etl tool, so it is (in theory) an alternative to Informatica, not an addition/companion to it

Comment: I have an architecture where Pocket ETL is proposed to be used to dump data from  the source to the sftp server. Is it worth in terms of security? Sorry I understand its not related to Informatica or the question in context here.